# gulp, tasks works individually but not in group

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

I have 3 task to be run sequentially : `clean`, `mincat` and then `serve`

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var webserver = require('gulp-webserver');
var usemin = require('gulp-usemin');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var minifyHtml = require('gulp-minify-html');
var minifyCss = require('gulp-minify-css');
var rev = require('gulp-rev');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');
var del = require('del');
var sequential = require('run-sequence');

gulp.task('clean', function () {
    del(['./build/*.*', './build/*']);
});

gulp.task('mincat', function () {
    gulp.src('./Index.html')
      .pipe(usemin({
          css: [minifyCss(), 'concat'],
          html: [minifyHtml({ empty: true })],
          js: [uglify()],
          js1: [uglify()]
      }))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/'));
});

gulp.task('serve', function () {
    gulp.src('build')
      .pipe(webserver({
          host: 'localhost',
          port: 8080,
          livereload: true,
          open: true
      }));
});

gulp.task('dev', function () {
    sequential('clean','mincat','serve');
});
```

If I run the 3 tasks from command prompt one by one, it works

```
gulp clean
gulp mincat
gulp serve
```

Now I created a task to run all the 3 using single command, it doesnt work. I tried all the forms

1. added run-sequential plugin

   `gulp.task('dev', function () {
       sequential('clean','mincat','serve');
   });`
2. initially run in parallel

   `gulp.task('dev', ['clean','mincat','serve'])`
3. I also tried to separate the serve

   `gulp.task('dev', ['clean','mincat'] function () {
      gulp.start('serve');
    })`

but non of these work, can someone point out the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your *2* can't work, since the gulp dependencies are all runned in parallel, without specific order. The *3* can work, but it's not really recommended since it not follow the gulp guidelines.

This let us the *1*. What you did is correct, but the problem you're experiencing is that gulp does not know when your tasks are finished, so it's equivalent to run everything in parallel.

To make a task synchronous, you will have to return it's stream. Since `del` is not a stream, you only have to use the `callback`. For your `serve`, I don't think you have to do it, since it's launched at last.

This will look like:

```
gulp.task('clean', function (cb) {
  del(['./build/*.*', './build/*'], cb);
});

gulp.task('mincat', function () {
  return gulp.src('./Index.html')
    .pipe(usemin({
      css: [minifyCss(), 'concat'],
      html: [minifyHtml({ empty: true })],
      js: [uglify()],
      js1: [uglify()]
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/'));
});
```

I don't understand why you could have `.js1` files thought, and by the way, your `index.html` should be lowercase :)

Comment: regarding: `1. js1` I have to js sections one for third party js and one for my local app js files `2. index.html` will lowercase that

Comment: oh okay, don't forget the `cb` of `clean` too

Comment: but then how do I pass `cb` to 'clean'??

Comment: I've put the example in my answer, the first parameter of a gulp task is its callback, and you have to specify it on your `del` call

Comment: Your `dev` task will look the same as you did with `run-sequence`

Comment: so then where am I passing the callback needed for the `clean` task

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68073/discussion-between-apercu-and-harishr).